# how forward iterator are used as multi-pass algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I read a line that Forward iterators are combination of Input and Output iterators . What I want to know is meaning of this statement "Performing operations on a forward iterator that is dereferenceable never makes its iterator value non-dereferenceable"

Comment: Forward iterators are not "combination of input and output iterators". What, ***specifically*** don't you understand about the meaning of the statement in question?

Answer (score 1):

Input and output iterators are allowed to be single-pass. That is, you are only permitted to dereference them once time before you must increment them to the next element.

Forward iterators may be a combination of input and output iterators *grammatically*, but they also require that you can dereference the same value multiple times. They have non-syntactical requirements beyond their APIs.

Input/output iterators can represent ephemeral sequences of data, such as streams of data from external sources that you aren't storing for later use. A forward iterator represents a range of data that is stored in memory or one that can be recomputed/reloaded.

Comment: So to answer the title question, I assume you can't use a forward iterator for algorithms that need to traverse data multiple times? (unless you create a copy)

Comment: @M.A: That is the *opposite* of what "you can dereference the same value multiple times" means.